# Why can a function change an objects variable but not a variable

Tags: python

Here's what I don't understand, if I made a function that would change the value of a variable, this would only save it in the function, so it won't change the global variable.

```
var = 10

def change_var(variable):
    variable += 1

change_var(var)

print(var)
________________________

10
```

However, when I use the variable of a object (I'm not sure what this is called), it works completely fine. This just doesn't makes sense to me that one works but the other doesn't.
This is what I mean

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

object_ = foo(10)

def change_var(object_):
    object_.var += 1

change_var(object_)

print(object_.var)
________________________

11
```

I want an explanation on why one works but not the other

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct? The function in the first code requires an argument and yet you didn't provide any

Comment: ... similarly, `__init__` requires one positional argument.

Comment: You are passing an object in both cases, there is no such thing as "passing a variable". However, in the first case, the object is immutable, it is an `int`. In the second case, it is not immutable, it is an instance of your custom class. That's the only difference here. The answer you accepted is completely incorrect. There is only a single evaluation strategy in Python, and it is neither call by value nor call by reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python passes variables *by Value*, but objects *by Reference*.
So if you modify a variable, you modify your local copy, not the original; if you modify an object, you modify the original.

Comment: Absolutely incorrect. This answer is confused in two ways. Python only has **a single evaluation strategy** which is neither call by value nor call by reference. Secondly, there is no distinction between passing "a variable" and passing an object